# Searching for an item in php

Tags: php, html

At the moment when I press the Search button on my html page it adds a new car to my table but I want to be able to search for a car from a list of cars I have created on MySql. I have a car_displayed code which will display the cars in a table once a search is in place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="Searing for a car" />
<meta name="keywords" content="PHP, MySql" />
<title>Retrieving records to HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Car Search</h1>
<?php
    require_once ("settings.php"); //connection info
    $conn = @mysqli_connect($host,
        $user,
        $pwd,
        $sql_db
    );
    $make = trim($_POST["carmake"]);
    $model = trim($_POST["carmodel"]);
    $price = trim($_POST["price"]);
    $yom = trim($_POST["yom"]);
    $sql_table="cars";
    $query = "insert into $sql_table (make, model, price) values ('$make', '$model', '$price')";
    //execute the query -we should really check to see if the batabase exists first.
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    //checks if the exeution was succcessful
    if (!$result) {
            echo "<p class=\"wrong\">Something is wrong with ", $query, "</p>";
            // would not show in a production script
        } else {
            // display an operation successful message
            echo "<p class=\"ok\">Successfully Searched Car record</p>";
        } // if successful query operation

        // close the database connection
        mysqli_close($conn);
     // if successful database connection
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) documentation. You need to change your current query to a "SELECT".

Comment: Why not just make a `select` query?

Comment: @GerardCuadras Well I can be stupid sometimes. So I just needed to change 'insert into' to 'select' correct?

Comment: For example, if you want to select the model and price when searching the model: `SELECT from $sql_table mode,name WHERE model LIKE %$searchtext%`. Where `$searchtext` is the text the user is searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of insert a new car, look for it with a ´select` query like

`$query = "select model, price from $sql_table where make LIKE %$make%"`

Once executed, `$result` will contain the info requested.

PS: I've guessed `make` is the primary key on your table.